# How to find the code error which turns my LED console into the "matrix"

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, console, ubuntu-16.04

I'm doing some university tasks and I managed to change the code and achieve the task properly but the console bugs out and acts strange.

The image can be found here since I don't have 10 reputation yet
https://imgur.com/a/X7a6bpa

You have the linux Ubuntu LED console and you can toggle the white and red lights as well as increase or decrease the speed at which they flash between a max and min amount. 
The task was to have the console write out the current state of leds and the delay at which they flash.
Now I made that but due to interference, wrong semaphore usage or some code errors the console starts having random numbers appear in different parts of it. I've searched and couldn't find any reason for it. I'm also not sure what I'm actually looking at so an answer might already exist.

This is running Ubuntu 16.04.6 Xebian as that's what the uni requires. It includes threads and semaphores. I tried changing the semaphores and code around but it didn't work. I'm also fairly new to threads and semaphores so they might be completely in the wrong places.

I added as little code as possible. The things I wrote are the *led_info_thr function and creation in main,the semaphore in *led_toggle_thr.

```
static bool flashing[2] = {false, false};
static int  flashing_delay[2] = {FLASH_INITIAL_DELAY, FLASH_INITIAL_DELAY};

static sem_t mutex;

void *led_toggle_thr(void *arg);
void *keyboard_thr(void *arg);
void *led_info_thr(void *arg);
void inc_delay(int i);
void dec_delay(int i);

int main (void) {
pthread_t thread[4];
int rc;
unsigned long i;
sem_init(&mutex,0 ,1);

console_init();

for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, led_toggle_thr, (void *)i);
    assert(rc == 0);
}
rc = pthread_create(&thread[2], NULL, keyboard_thr, NULL);
assert(rc == 0);
rc = pthread_create(&thread[3], NULL, led_info_thr, NULL);
assert(rc == 0);    
while (true) {
    /* skip */
}
exit(0);
}

void *led_toggle_thr(void *arg) {
unsigned long id = (long)arg;
while (true) {
    if (flashing[id]) {F
    sem_wait(&mutex);
        led_toggle((leds_t)id);
    sem_post(&mutex);
    }
    usleep(flashing_delay[id]);
}
}

void *led_info_thr(void *arg) {
char flashing_str[2]={'N','N'};
while(true)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if(flashing[i] == true) flashing_str[i] = 'Y';
    else flashing_str[i] = 'N';
            sem_wait(&mutex);
    lcd_write_at(i, 0, "LED%d F:%c D:%d", i, flashing_str[i], flashing_delay[i]);
    sem_post(&mutex);
}
}
return NULL;
}
```

`

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  Notice: the posted code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed ``#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes?

Comment: OT: regarding: `assert(rc == 0);`  this tells the user nothing about why the code crashed.   Suggest: `if( pthread_create(&thread[3], NULL, led_info_thr, NULL) !=0 ) { perror( "pthread_create failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT: this: `void *led_info_thr(void *arg) {` will not cleanly compile!  Suggest: `void *led_info_thr(void *arg) { (void) arg;`

Comment: If I added the full code it would have taken three times as much and I don't know how to format it properly yet. Anyway the problem was interference from the concurrency. I've found a way to fix it.

Comment: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.   2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: this: `void *led_toggle_thr(void *arg) {
unsigned long id = (long)arg;` will not cleanly compile.  Suggest: `void *led_toggle_thr(void *arg) {
unsigned long id = *(long*)arg;`

Comment: OT: regarding: `while (true) {
    /* skip */
}`  This is not a good idea.  Suggest: `for( int i = 0; i<3; i++ ) { pthread_join(  thread[i]  NULL ); }`

Comment: OT: using semaphores is rather overkill for the presented problem.  Suggest using: `pthread_multex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;  and the functions: `pthread_mutex_lock( mymutex );` and `pthread_mutex_unlock( mymutex );`

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, led_toggle_thr, (void *)i);
    assert(rc == 0);
}`  Then the code calls pthread_create( ... ) with `thread[]` with index of 2 and 3, but index 2 is already in use.   This is a problem. (not the underlying problem, but still a problem

Comment: Since part of the code is the instructors and part is yours, Please indicate which is only yours

Comment: OT: the function: `assert()` is 'ok' for debugging code but not good for a final project